# Import styles bootstrap in Next Js project React SSR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, next.js, reactstrap

I have a problem that the styles are not loaded in next js. According to the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/#importing-css--sass--less--stylus-files), I can import css or scss files to next Js. But when I add reactstrap and bootstrap to the project, the components work for me without problem, but not bootstrap styles. The purpose is to create an React app with SSR. I hope you can help me with that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

create a next.config.js and add code below for sass support

```
const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");
module.exports = withSass({
  /* config options here */
});
```

create a style.scss

```
@import url("https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

then import to your react component

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing adding [@zeit/next-css](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-css)

Comment: It’s better to send this as a comment.